# Is it possible to streaming RTSP (live) videos from camera in an electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, desktop-application, rtsp

I'm new in electron development, so please inform me if it is possible to stream RTSP with electron, and what are all the steps needed.

If that's not possible in electron, I would be open to another desktop application framework that would work with RTSP video.

Answer (score -2):

Try this repository [github repository](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/camera)

It's a simple app using camera.

```
<video src="rtp://myserver.com/path/to/stream">
    Your browser does not support the VIDEO tag and/or RTP streams.
</video>
```

or maybe

```
<video src="http://myserver.com:1935/path/to/stream/myPlaylist.m3u8">
    Your browser does not support the VIDEO tag and/or RTP streams.
</video>
```

Comment: Bansa: am asking about live stream rtsp from cloud.